# CSS positioning issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, melonjs

I'm creating a game using melonJS. I would like to dynamically position dialog boxes over the NPCs.

In full screen, it looks fine.

[image]

When I shrink the viewport, the positioning stays absolute and therefore looks bad. But if I don't position absolute, I won't be able to place it relative to the NPC's coordinates as such:

`$("#dialogBox").css({top: game.data.currentNPC_y+50, left: game.data.currentNPC_x-50, position:'absolute'});`

[image]

Any way around this?

---

**Edit:**

When I use the following, the code doesn't scale as mentioned above, but at least it's still near the NPC and on the canvas:

```
        $("#dialogBox").css({
            top: game.data.currNPC_y+50, 
            left: game.data.currNPC_x-50, 
            position:'absolute'
        });
```

[image]

When I use the code you suggested, it appears outside the canvas:

```
        $("#dialogBox").css({
            position : "absolute",
            left     : (game.data.currentNPC_x - 50) * me.sys.scale.x,
            top      : (game.data.currentNPC_y - 500) * me.sys.scale.y
        });
```

[image]

Comment: are you scaling the rest of the objects when the viewport shrinks? If so, then you need to recalculate as the viewport shrinks.

Comment: Why are you subtracting large magic numbers like 500? Assuming your variable `game.data.currentNPC_y` is correctly referencing the entity position Y-coordinate, the rest of the code would work.

Comment: That's a typo it's meant to be 50.  Regardless it still appears outside the canvas

Answer (score 2):

Scale the DOM absolute left by `me.sys.scale.x` and absolute top by `me.sys.scale.y`:

```
$("#dialogBox").css({
    "position" : "absolute",
    "left"     : (game.data.currentNPC_x - 50) * me.sys.scale.x,
    "top"      : (game.data.currentNPC_y + 50) * me.sys.scale.y
});
```

You can scale the element's width and height as well to better integrate.

Finally, you should listen to the [WINDOW_ONRESIZE](http://melonjs.github.io/docs/me.event.html#WINDOW_ONRESIZE) event to rescale the element dynamically as the user changes the window size, or mobile device orientation, etc.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the answer. When I use this code, the text box appears below the canvas. See above edit